# Why when I try to set ActionBar.CustomView.SetBackgroundColor (Color.White); Does the application crash?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Why when I try to set `ActionBar.CustomView.SetBackgroundColor (Color.White);` Does the application crash?

I tried installing the ToolbarItems background via style, toolbar.axml via ResourceDictionary but not one of these methods works for me - I think because I'm too dumb.

Now this option is the easiest for me, since there is only one line of code, but somewhere you can see the conflict comes from style or toolbar.axml or something else.
`ActionBar.CustomView.SetBackgroundColor (Color.White);`

my app.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using MyApp1.Services;
using MyApp1.Views;

namespace MyApp1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {

        static Data.TodoItemDatabase database;
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new AppShell();

        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        // Handle when your app start
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }

        public static Data.TodoItemDatabase Database
        {
            get
            {
                if (database == null)
                {
                    database = new Data.TodoItemDatabase(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "TodoSQLite.db3"));
                }
                return database;
            }
        }

        public int ResumeAtTodoId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are not using `ActionBar` you are using `Toolbar` and to change the colour for that you got to `styles.xml` and change the theme colors or go to `Toolbar.xml` and Change the background there.

Comment: @FreakyAli ths you. Can I somehow change the background of ToolbarItems from the code in the mainactivity file?

Comment: @FreakyAli How to change the background of toolbarItems? I know how to change the text color ```<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#2196F3</item>```

Comment: When you say background of toolbar item is it the background of the image?

Comment: @FreakyAli I just need a white background color. Anyway, the image will be or just COLOR.WHITE. The simpler the better.

Comment: show me your app.xaml.cs

Comment: @FreakyAli i update post. maybe you mean activity?

Comment: Are we talking about Xamarin.Forms Android? or Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1:

You can set the style of `TitleView` in Forms . You can create a base `Navigation Page`and set the style of `TitleView`

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="White" >
       //...
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

#### Solution 2

You can try creating a **Custom Renderer** and set it as the base class for all pages in the app. Within this custom renderer you can try to set the background color and other style as you want in `CustomTitleView` .

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Page), typeof(AndroidNavigationPageRenderer )]
public class AndroidNavigationPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    private CustomTitleView _titleView;
    public NavigationSearchRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        
        var activity = this.Context as FormsAppCompatActivity;
        if (activity == null)
            return;

        var toolbar = activity.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        _titleView= new TitleView(Context);
        toolbar.AddView(_titleView);
    }

}
```